# How to detect a mobile device in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a website I want to use specific CSS rules for mobile devices. What I want is the following:

- create a link on a phone number, and make it clickable for mobile devices
- code example: `<a href="tel:+1234567890">+1234567890</a>` (similar to mailto:john@hotmail.com)
- Clicking this link on a normal computer will probably produce an error message saying that they don't know the tel-protocol.

I want to use CSS to hide the phone number with the link on non-mobile devices, and display another element with a plain phone number.  I could use the media="handheld" option, but it seems Android and iOS ignore this. A clean CSS-method is preferred, but it's no problem if Javascript (or JQuery) is needed.

My question is now about this tel-link, but I probably will use the same method for other changes to the stylesheet for mobile devices.

Comment: You would need to use somesort of Framework for mobile devices and hope that it has taken care of things. It would be bit exhaustive to support each type on your own from scratch.

Comment: I don't get it. What does CSS have to do with a phone number link? Do you mean you want to use CSS to apply styles to these links only on mobile devices?

Comment: You can't use CSS to create links. Not all mobile devices support the tel: scheme. Not all non-mobile devices do not support the tel: scheme.

Comment: In addition to what Quentin said, what’s the harm in having the link in non-supporting browsers? It simply won’t work, with an error message similar to “this browser doesn’t support the ‘tel’ protocol”, which sounds more or less intelligible to me.

Comment: You're correct that CSS can't create links, but it can hide elements. So it could hide the a-tel-element, and display another element with the phone number without the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what i use to check if the given request comes from a mobile device:

```
$mobile_browser = '0';

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}    

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'mac') > 0) {
        $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'ios') > 0) {
        $mobile_browser = 1;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'android') > 0) {
        $mobile_browser = 1;
}

if($mobile_browser == 0)
{
    //its not a mobile browser
    echo"You are not a mobile browser";
} else {
    //its a mobile browser
    echo"You are a mobile browser!";
}
?>
```

I made this with help of a mate of mine, if you have tips or corrections for me please give in comments:)

Comment: That is PHP, but that's not a problem.

Comment: I tried it on my development machine (ubuntu 11.04 with firefox 4). When I run that code in my browser, I get a 1 back, which would mean that my desktop runs a mobile browser.

Comment: Sorry, had a problem with the code; I do get a 0, so not mobile.

Comment: If it works for you thats great :) please flag as the answer so other people can find it too.

Comment: Tested it on XP/Firefox, XP/IE6, Ubu/Chrome, Ubu/FF4, Android, Wine/Safari and Wine/IE7, and all work like it should.

Comment: Awesome:) i only tested it on win7 and Ubu. Glad it works in all browsers:)

Comment: I did some more tests. FF4, Safari 5 and Chrome on OSX10.6 work correctly. The only problem is my iPod with iOS 3.1.3, which it doesn't recognize as a mobile browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a selector for href's using "tel" you can use css attr "starts with" selectors, like so...

```
a[href^="tel"] { color: red; }
```

See my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/gn9Ld/

Comment: JSFiddle is cool! :-) And you're example is clear, although not exactly what I need, but that's not a big problem I think.

Comment: Unlike my previous comment, I now realize that your suggestion does not solve my problem (using a specific stylesheet for mobile browsers). Still it's useful as it helped me realize that I can just add a class to the link and set the cursor to arrow. That way, desktop browsers won't invite the user to click it, and mobile browsers (which don't use a mouse cursor) still can use the link. And whether I use your method with a css-condition or add a class is not really that important to me.

Answer (score 3):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use callto:

```
<a href="callto://+112345767890">Call me at +112345767890</a>
```

since you're developing for mobile devices i think you should have a read on CSS3 Media Queries if you haven't done so yet.

http://ubelly.com/2011/04/css3-media-queries-explained/?amp&amp

Comment: Is callto skype or voip specific or is there no difference?

Comment: I've just tried using 'callto' as well as 'tel' in hyperlinks and on my Mac (Google Chrome / Firefox) it tried to call using Skype but on my iPhone (Safari) it behaved exactly the same as using 'tel'. Be aware though that for me, the prefix had to be 'callto:' rather than 'callto://' as the latter did not work in Firefox or Chrome.