# Phone number with letters - click to call

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have a phone number that contains letters (for effect) be recognized by mobile devices, and ONLY mobile devices, as a click-to-call number?

The client is a CPA and they happen to have 4CPA as the last 4 digits and this is really important to them... but what is important to me is that this website is usable.

I found this question:
[How to detect a mobile device in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439777/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-a-web-page)

but I am not sure how to implement the PHP nor write the PHP to fill in the if/then.

(I was hoping to do this without PHP.)

Comment: How about a `<a href="tel:+18002255631">800-CALL-ME1</a>`

Comment: This is still visible on a normal webpage and then throws an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the following HTML on a webpage and accessing and clicking on the link on an iPhone makes it call the number [+1 (555) 222-333]:

```
<a href="tel:+1-555-ABCDEF">+1-555-ABCDEF</a>
```

*Update:*

Mobile-only (**iPhone** and **Android Mobile**) solution:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|Android.*Mobile)/i))
    {
        $('a[data-tel]').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('href', 'tel:' + $(this).data('tel'));
        });
    }
})
</script>

<a data-tel="+1-555-ABCDEF">+1-555-ABCDEF</a>
```

This will only *linkify* the phone number in browsers with the user-agent string containing `iPhone` **or** `Android` and `Mobile`.

(See: [Detecting an Android phone](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/03/mo-better-to-also-detect-mobile-user.html))

Comment: did you mean to put the actual number as the href, or does it really work that way?

Comment: It works, give it a try. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: I could use responsive CSS to only show it to small browsers this way I guess, but iPod touch would be bugged.

Comment: See updated solution to make it a link on mobile devices only.