# Web app: Hide a div except android browsers

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i had developed a mobile web application used Jquery mobile framework...
my home page i had added a **div** with some instructions for who browse my website android device...

```
<div class="instruction">
     Some instructions for android users here...
</div>
```

what my question is, i need this div display only when my website under running android device/browsers, if when running my website except android browsers  eg: iOs, nokia, etc... just need to hide this div... it means this div content allow read only for who browsing my website with android devices/browsers....

any idea.?? thanks

Comment: navigator.userAgent. Try to check for this inside Javascript..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439777/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-a-web-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;      
var isAndroid = (agent.indexOf("Android")  > 0);     

if (isAndroid ){ 
    $("div.instruction").show();
}
```

There are also other more precise ways of device detection and you can find them in this answer: **[What are available solutions of a browser / mobile phone detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15055352/1848600)**

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xHA46/

Answer (score 2):

Check user agent and do action -

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) {
    $("div.instruction").show();
}
```